# post request to node server not hitting endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to axios.post from my react front end to my node server!
the react client and node server are both running locally - within the same parent directory. Client running on port 3000 and Server 3400.

When i change the code to app.get and access the url localhost:3400/refundCalc it works and displays the hello message when its res.send. it doesnt work as app.post but it doesnt work using the axios post either!

the error code is: Failed to load http://localhost:3400/refundCalc: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I posted all of the react front end code but really its just the getRefundCalc function where the axios.post is thats the problem, i think?

my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const port = 3400;
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))


// to send the get refundCalcRequest
app.post('/refundCalc', function (req, res) {
    console.log('response from client - get refund request ' + res)
    console.log('request from client - get refund request ' + req)

    res.end('HELLOOOO')

})
```

My react front end:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import axios from 'axios'

  class MediaCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

    super(props)
    this.state = {

    }

  }


  getRefundCalc(props) {
    console.log('we are calling the getrefundcalc call on button click')
    console.log('the props of the card, are they different for each card?' + JSON.stringify(props))

    axios.post(`http://localhost:3400/refundCalc`, { props }) <-- HERES THE CALL.
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
  }




 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const rtnBtnClicked = this.state.rtnBtnClicked;
    return (
      <Card className={classes.card} onClick={() => this.getRefundCalc(this.props)}>
        <CardActionArea >
          <CardMedia
            className={classes.media}
            image={this.props.data.imageLinks.image_src}
          />
          <CardContent >
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h5" style={{ fontSize: 9 }}>
              {this.props.data.items.title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="h5" style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
              Price:£ {this.props.data.items.price}
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="primary" >
            {rtnBtnClicked ? 'Remove From Refund' : 'Add to Refund'}
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

My expected result is for the post request to hit my endpoint and console the results :D

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const corst = require('cors'); // requiring cors
const port = 3400;

app.use(cors()) // adding cors middleware to allow request from other domains
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

...
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

Comment: Thank you :) what exactly does cors do?

Comment: Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served

Comment: I would love to know if this had worked for you @Sparlarva